# PhpStorm - Use tab and Emmet to wrap code

Tags: phpstorm

I love emmet. `div.container` and then pressing tab has made my life so much easier.

But assume you have a div like this:
`<div class="myDiv"> </div>` and you want to wrap that inside a container.

What I've been doing so far is typing out

```
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Then I copy paste `myDiv` in between.

There has to be a simpler way, no?

What I'm looking for is being able to put my cursor in front of `<div class="myDiv">`, type out `div.container` then press tab, and the result would end up like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="myDiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

Not even sure what the term for this would be. Searching for "phpstorm wrapping" doesn't give me what I need.

Is there a setting for this somewhere that I've missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select your text/code
2. `Code | Surround With...` (or `Code | Surround with Live Template...` -- the menu will be almost the same for HTML context)
3. Choose `Emmet` option in appeared popup
4. Type your emmet sequence

**P.S.**
It's possible to assign custom shortcut to `Surround with Emmet` action so it can be called directly (one shortcut that would replace steps #2 and #3). This can be done in `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` -- just search for the aforementioned action (using search field).

Comment: on Mac, the key shortcut is CMD+ALT+T and then You have context menu where You can select emmet

Comment: If You don't know the key shortcut, You can also use SHIFT+CMD+A and start typing `surround` - you will get surround with emmet option as well

Comment: @RafalKozlowski Shortcuts for these actions are already clearly shown/visible in the menu (next to action's name). In such circumstances there is no real need to use `Help | Find Action...` to look them up. But yes -- that's a very good way to find it out if user does not know the shortcut (and exact location where action is located in the menu) or does not remember the exact action name; it is also useful to invoke actions that are not available in main menu or when main menu is not (yet) accessible (e.g. from Welcome screen).

Comment: Thanks I guess it's the closest thing I can get. Would be nice if Emmets tab completion works in conjunction with wrapping code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `div.container`. A simple `.container` does the job also. A div is automatically generated if you don't specify the element.
You can do nested elements with `>`. 
In your case it would be: `.container>.myDiv`. If you want to surround existing items, look at @LazyOne answer. The shortcut for it is [Ctrl] + [Alt] + j (on default settings at least).
For more information look [here](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/). (was just a quick google search for "emmet PHPstorm" but it looks good)